# Identifying elements on a ReactJS webpage using Selenium, is their a better way?

Tags: reactjs, selenium, testing

I am trying to write web driven tests using Selenium on a webpage built with reactjs. I am able to grab my elements by xpath however this is not ideal and very limiting.

1. If any changes happen to the website the xpath will not work.
2. all the class names are identical with no other attributes to grab, as well the class names change because they are dynamically built by react.
3. There are no other attributes to use.
4. Cant use the CSSSelector because the css name is also built by react.

My main problems keep popping up when I want a specific element, like one I just built or how to manipulate a specific one in a list.

I keep getting stumped on the same problem for each test I try to write, no unique identifiers. I am not familiar with reactJs but is this a common problem with Selenium?

Comment: Sounds like React components that have been designed with zero regard to testability outside of React unit tests. You are correct that using XPath will lead to tears. The folks developing the components should provide some form of identity that will not change (or at least not change much). *How* the class names get constructed is immaterial; using something consistent to allow external integration testing is just a good idea.

Comment: Yes, this web page was created originally without the intent of automated testing. So is there any way to use selenium in this sort of environment in its current state?

Comment: @Jesse Bell, an XPath is as reliable as a CSS selector or ID. What makes a locator brittle is tree dependencies and relying on auto-generated/meaningless attributes. For instance `by.xpath("id('myid')")` is as reliable as `by.css("[id='myid']")` or `by.id("myid")`. Note that you also have the option to locate an element by text with either a JavaScript injection or with an XPath (`.//*[not(./*)][normalize-space()='my text']` or `.//*[string()[contains(., 'my text')]]`).

Answer (score 3):

It's common practice to use a `data-test` attribute on your HTML elements to assist in browser-based testing;, whether it's static or rendered by a JS framework; I would recommend that you request that the developers include these attributes throughout the codebase in order to allow you to easily target the elements you want to test without worrying about class names or id attributes changing.